# MS Dynamics : Entity Name List and there fields list

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am working on the msdynamics connector in C#.net.In the connector i want to retreive the list of entity object name i.e lead,contacts etc.Also i want to retreive there respective fields list.I am working on Vs2010 and used Passport login.

Comment: Please try giving more context about this question. Which connector you are using? It's a connector or a simple application accessing to CRM Dynamics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.retrieveallentitiesrequest.aspx), which returns the metadata for all entities (logical names, attributes, etc).